# How do I process following kind of input using cin?

Tags: c++, input, cin

Input is as follows:

```
2

3 2 1 4
10.3 12.1 2.9 1.9

2 1 3
9.8 2.3 1.2
```

So 2 is the number of test cases. Then there is an blank line. Then a test case follows. A single test consists of two lines of respectively integer and floating point values. Number of integers are equal to number of floating point values. Then again a blank line and second test follows.
I am facing two problems: First, if I knew how many numbers there are going to be I could have used for loop and second one there are blank lines after test case and between test cases. I don't know how to read them using cin or ignore them. I will be storing these values in vector. Thanks

Comment: Do you know of `getline` and `ostringstream`?

Comment: I know getline but not ostringstream. I know I could use getline(cin,s) to read new line in a string s. I wanted to do it with using cin & '\n'.

Comment: With `cin` alone you can't (I think) know when you passed a line. The best solution in this case would be to read a line, pass it to an `ostringstream sin(the_line);` and read `while (sin >> num) {...}`

Comment: @Shahbaz: You should make an answer.

Comment: @Shahbaz And what about newline between two lines of a test case?

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, ok I will. I'm starting to feel bad about answering C++ questions. Some of the people active in this tag are quite ... zealous.

Comment: @user1425223 I've posted an answer that cover all the corner cases, including the newline between two lines of a test case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `getline` function to read lines, such as:

```
string line;
std::getline(std::cin, line);
```

Then, you need to parse the line. There are two cases (after reading the number of test cases). Either you hit a blank line, or have `n` integers. You can read the integers one by one and add them to your vector. If you got 0 integers after the buffer is finished, then it was an empty line:

```
unsigned int n;
std::ostringstream sin(line);
while (sin >> number)
{
    // add number to your vector
    ++n;
}
if (n == 0)
    // go back and try getline again
```

Now that you have `n`, reading the next line with floats should be easy. Just use a loop since you know the number of floats is the same as the number of integers for each test case.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the following program does what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

int main() {
    // Identify the number of tests
    std::string ntests_str;
    std::getline(std::cin, ntests_str);
    int ntests = boost::lexical_cast<int>(ntests_str);

    // Iterate over all tests
    for (int i = 0; i < ntests; i++) {
        // Read the integer numbers
        std::string integers;
        while (integers.empty())
            std::getline(std::cin, integers);

        // Split the integers into a vector of strings
        std::vector<std::string> intstr_vec;
        boost::split(intstr_vec, integers, boost::is_any_of(" "));

        // Convert to integers
        std::vector<int> int_vec;
        int_vec.resize(intstr_vec.size());
        std::transform(intstr_vec.begin(), intstr_vec.end(), int_vec.begin(),
            [&](const std::string& s) {
                return boost::lexical_cast<int>(s);
            }
        );

        // Read the floating point numbers
        std::string fnumbers;
        std::getline(std::cin, fnumbers);

        // Split the floating-point numbers into a vector of strings
        std::vector<std::string> fstr_vec;
        boost::split(fstr_vec, fnumbers, boost::is_any_of(" "));

        // Convert the floating point numbers
        std::vector<float> float_vec;
        float_vec.resize(fstr_vec.size());
        std::transform(fstr_vec.begin(), fstr_vec.end(), float_vec.begin(),
            [&](const std::string& s) {
                return boost::lexical_cast<float>(s);
            }
        );

        // Print the test case
        std::cout << "== Test case " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Integers: ";
        std::copy(int_vec.begin(), int_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Floats: ";
        std::copy(float_vec.begin(), float_vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<float>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
./prog1
1

3 2 1 4
10.3 12.1 2.9 1.9

== Test case 0
Integers: 3 2 1 4
Floats: 10.3 12.1 2.9 1.9
```